# SAS: How do I pick conditional observations per by-group

Tags: sas

I have a SAS data set, which I have sorted according to my needs. I want to split it into BY groups and, for each group, output each observation until the first occurrence of a particular value in a particular column.

```
ID      No  C1  Year2   C3  Date (DD/MM/YYYY)
---------------------------------------------------------      
AB123   4   B4  2008E   OC  09/04/2008
AB123   3   B4  2008E   EL  09/04/2008
AB123   2   B4  2008E   ZZ  09/04/2008
AB123   1   B4  2008E   OC  09/04/2008
AB123   0   B4  2008E   ZZ  09/04/2008
AB123   1   B4  2008E   OC  06/02/2008
AB123   0   B4  2008E   ZZ  06/02/2008
```

This is one BY group: the data set is grouped by ID, C1, Year2 and sorted by ID, C1, Year2, Date(desc), No(desc). Further instances of each of ID, C1 and Year2 could occur anywhere in the data set, but the 3 variables define each BY group.

I want to output all observations per BY group up to and including the first occurrence of ZZ in C3. So above I would want the first 3 observations output (or flagged) and then move on to the next BY group.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you need any more details of the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way that should work.

```
data have;
input ID $ No C1 $ Year2 $ C3 $ Date :DDMMYY10.;
format date DDMMYY10.;
cards;
AB123   4   B4  2008E   OC  09/04/2008
AB123   3   B4  2008E   EL  09/04/2008
AB123   2   B4  2008E   ZZ  09/04/2008
AB123   1   B4  2008E   OC  09/04/2008
AB123   0   B4  2008E   ZZ  09/04/2008
AB123   1   B4  2008E   OC  06/02/2008
AB123   0   B4  2008E   ZZ  06/02/2008
;
run;

data want (drop=stopflag);
set have;
by id c1 year2;
retain stopflag;
if max(first.id,first.c1,first.year2)=1 then stopflag=0;
if c3='ZZ' and stopflag=0 then do;
    output;
    stopflag=1;
end;
if stopflag=0 then output;
run;
```